# Как у Вас сделана функция восстановления пароля?

Tags: php, javascript

Как у Вас сделана функция восстановления пароля? Актуально ли ставить капчу? Или мир изменился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На одном из проектов капчу предлагали вводить при востановлении пароля, если ip не соответствовал адресам, с которых заходил аккаунт, для которого запросили востановление.
А так - два поля логин и мыло. При соответствии генерируется ссылка для подтверждения.

Comment: Если Email и имя пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), лично я в своих проектах, уже не использую каптчу в принципе (*не факт, что я прав, но меня самого раздражает эта фишка*). А для восстановления пароля, использую мыло пользователя и в одном проекте - SMS, но там случай отдельный. В общем, для восстановления, на мой взгляд, генерировать уникальную ссылку и отправлять на зарегистрированный Email - вполне достаточно.

Comment: А как же обратная сторона спама или прочего?

Comment: Кстати, про смс - можете дать ссылку на шлюз-сервис?